# Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've upgraded React to 0.13.x from 0.12.2 (also react-router) and unfortunately I've got this warning.

> Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.

In my opinion problem is caused by key property in my `<RouteHandler>`.
In React 0.12.x I was using `getRoutes()` function to set key.

```
    render: function () {
        var name = this.getRoutes().reverse()[0].name;
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Router.RouteHandler 
                    key={name} 
                    places={this.state.places} 
                    mode={this.state.mode}
                    ...
```

and then React knew which component use. It worked something like

http://theimagehost.net/upload/798bf2195d31a2926250e6fbca806254.gif

At now

http://theimagehost.net/upload/9990cea32e13d443806b829ccbdc964d.gif

I don't know how to tell react which component should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use `key` property when rendering a list of components based on a dynamic array. The error should be gone once you rename the property from `key` to something else

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have this error though that I've changed all items `key={name}` to `index={name}`.